# In Android : How to listen/monitor a specific app's network activities

Tags: android, networking

I want to know to write a app to monitor the default browser in Android. Is it possible?

1. record the URL the user visit and the time when the user visit.
2. get the browser bookmarks.

Comment: I think you can't monitor the URLs as far as I know.

Comment: No, this is not possible using the standard API.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** 1. no, 2. short of

**Longer answer:**

1. Androids default API doesn't allow this. If you modify the device firmware (custom ROM) this might be possible by providing a modified version of the Android System WebView app. You would need to make changes to this app which allow other apps to monitor the URL's loaded.
2. In older versions of Android you could obtain the the browser bookmarks using the following code (Since Android 6.0 this isn't supported anymore: [Android 6.0 changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser)):

   ```
   final String[] columns = {Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL};
   Cursor query = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, columns, null, null, null);
   query.moveToFirst();
   while (query.moveToNext()) {
       String title = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
       String url = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
   }
   ```

   You do also need the following permission:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
   ```